# behavior of capacitor in case of open circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

[image: the behavior of the capacitor in open circuit as shown in the figure . assume the capacitor to be ideal]

the circuit is as shown in figure. the behavior of capacitor in this case ! what happens to the voltage at Node1 . I know the circuit isnt practical but i need theoretical explanantion of what might be output of this open circuit ?

Comment: How does a capacitor deal with DC signals? (Think in terms of the impedance of a capacitor)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Homework-style questions are not encouraged on the website, and they need to be about specific concepts or show effort.

Comment: The voltage at Node1 is undefined, but if you could measure it with an _ideal_ meter (i.e., infinite impedance), and if you changed the value of V2, then the voltage at Node1 would change by exactly the same amount.

Comment: It depends on the charge $Q$ on the capacitor (which cannot be determined from the information given). $\Delta V = \frac{Q}{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no path for a charging or discharging current, the voltage across the capacitor cannot change and so the voltage at node 1 is just the source voltage minus the (constant) capacitor voltage which must be specified as an 'initial' condition.

Another way to see this is to add a resistor from node 1 to ground and see that the voltage across the resistor is (from the standard RC circuit solution)

$$v_R(t) = \left(V_2 - \frac{Q(0)}{C_2}\right)e^{-t/RC_2}$$

In the limit as $R \rightarrow \infty$, the resistor goes to an open circuit and the exponential goes to one:

$$v_{R_\infty} = V_2 - \frac{Q(0)}{C_2}$$

For yet another approach, let the capacitor charge through a resistor, connected from node 1 to ground, to the voltage $V_2$.

The voltage across the resistor is now zero and so *you can remove the resistor without changing the voltage at node 1*.  That is, if you remove the resistor and replace it with an ideal voltmeter, the voltmeter will read a constant zero volts.

However, if you then *discharged* the capacitor by placing a resistor in parallel with it, once the voltage is zero across the capacitor, the voltmeter will now read 1V.  If you then remove that parallel resistor, the voltmeter will continue to read 1V.

This demonstrates two things:

- The voltage at node 1 *is* defined even if there is an open circuit
  there as you've drawn
- The voltage across the capacitor is an
  'initial' condition that must be specified.

---

Note:  Most if not all circuit simulators will not simulate a circuit with a floating node like you've drawn.  However, you can place a resistor between the floating node and ground and set its resistance to some very large value, e.g., $10^{15}\,\Omega$, the simulation will run, and the resistor is then *effectively* an open circuit.